# auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword is not a function

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have the following setup to connect to firebase but for some reason in the browser console it shows that  `auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword()` is not a function. Is there something wrong with my code?

```
        import { initializeApp } from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.0.2/firebase-app.js';
        import { getAuth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword } from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.0.2/firebase-auth.js';
        import { getFirestore } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.0.2/firebase-firestore.js"

        // TODO: Replace the following with your app's Firebase project configuration
        const firebaseConfig = {
            " my config here "
        };

        const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
        const auth = getAuth();
        const db = getFirestore();

        var button = document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", function () {
            var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
            var phone = document.getElementById("phone").value;
            var password = document.getElementById("password").value;

            auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(cred => {
                console.log(cred);
            })
        });
```

edit: I removed `auth.` from `auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(cred => { console.log(cred);` and now it is giving me the current error: ```Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot create property
'_canInitEmulator' on string 'heheboi@gmail.com'

```
at _performFetchWithErrorHandling (firebase-auth.js:1983)
at _performApiRequest (firebase-auth.js:1958)
at _performSignInRequest (firebase-auth.js:2030)
at signUp (firebase-auth.js:5330)
at createUserWithEmailAndPassword (firebase-auth.js:5978)
at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (register.html:48) ``
```

Answer (score 3):

Just update your code to the latest Firebase SDK 9:

```js
import { initializeApp } from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.0.2/firebase-app.js';
import { getAuth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword } from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.0.2/firebase-auth.js';
import { getFirestore } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.0.2/firebase-firestore.js"

// TODO: Replace the following with your app's Firebase project configuration
const firebaseConfig = {
    " my config here "
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const auth = getAuth();
const db = getFirestore();

var button = document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", function () {
    var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    var phone = document.getElementById("phone").value;
    var password = document.getElementById("password").value;

    createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password).then(cred => {
        console.log(cred);
    }).catch((error) => {
      const errorCode = error.code;
      const errorMessage = error.message;
      // ..
    });
});
```

You are already importing `createUserWithEmailAndPassword`. You can't use `auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword` anymore. You can find [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start) the latest docs.

Comment: I updated my code and now I am getting this error:
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot create property '_canInitEmulator' on string 'heheboi@gmail.com '
    at _performFetchWithErrorHandling (firebase-auth.js:1983)
    at _performApiRequest (firebase-auth.js:1958)
    at _performSignInRequest (firebase-auth.js:2030)
    at signUp (firebase-auth.js:5330)
    at createUserWithEmailAndPassword (firebase-auth.js:5978)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (register.html:48)

Comment: Can you pls try it with the updated code.

Comment: I tried and it worked thank you soo much!! I noticed that errors arise when I input an email that does not exist, is there a way to handle it cleanly instead of causing an error?

Comment: "You are already importing `createUserWithEmailAndPassword`. You can't use `auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword` anymore."  That's not completely true. Since the `compat` libraries use the modular SDKs under the hood, you can use both at the same time - it just requires that you (also) import the `compat` paths.

Comment: Sorry @FrankvanPuffelen. I tried just to make a short comment ;) Ofcource it's possible but as he is already using the new SDK and syntax (with some mistakes) I did not want to make it more complikated for him.

Comment: @MohammedRashid you can add a `catch` after the `then` to catch the errors so your code don't throw. I have updated the code in the answer to show how it's done.